# trigger UIViewAnimation after slider is done

Tags: xcode, block, uislider, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to trigger an UIViewAnimation Block with the slider. Basically I want a view to mode along the x axis. The distance is set by the slider.

The animation works ok, but I would like the animation to be triggered after I finished moving the slider. So far I've only accomplished moving the view at the same time as the slider.

Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the UISlider's `continuous` property to `NO`. It then sends events only when the user finished moving (lifted) his finger.

Comment: yeah, it works but I also need labels to be updated continiously. However, I found that linking the action to "touch up inside" does the trick. I wasn't easy to see in the simulator but it was allright on the device. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest setting the slider's continuous property to NO, as the other poster said, and then adding actions tied to both the value changed event and the UIControlEventTouchDragInside event. You should get a value changed event when the user releases the control, and a continuing stream of UIControlEventTouchDragInside events as the user drags the control.

Using touch up inside to get the final value might not work, since the user could touch on the control, drag to a new value, slide outside the control, then lift their finger. In that case the slider's value would be different, but the touchUpInside action would not fire.